# Как реализовать функцию drop в классе

Tags: python

Я хотел реализовать в классе функцию выбрасывания предметов из инвентаря. Однако переменные, которым я присвоил классы и атрибуты к ним, я решил записать в список. После чего я предлагаю игроку выбрать предмет, который он хочет выбросить. Я предоставил описание с помощью **str**, но если я хочу удалить элемент(переменную из списка), то не могу через атрибут name например узнать название элемента. Я предоставлю набросок для лучшего понимания:

```
class Item:
def __init__(self, name, item, container):
    self.name = name
    self.item = item
    self.container = container
def drop(self, item, container):
    return container.remove(item)
class Sword(Item):
def __init__(self, name, damage):
    self.name = name
    self.damage = damage
def __str__(self):
    return "Name: {}\nDamage: {}".format(self.name, self.damage)
class Armor(Item):
def __init__(self, name, defend):
    self.name = name
    self.defend = defend
def __str__(self):
    return "Name: {}\nProtect: {}".format(self.name, self.defend)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Wooden_sword = Sword("Деревянный меч", 1)
    Leather_armor = Armor("Кожаная броня", 1)
    inventory = [Leather_armor,Wooden_sword]
while True:
    user_input = input("Хотите выкинуть предмет?\n")
    if user_input.lower() == "да":
        for i in inventory:
            print(i)
        item = input("Выберите предмет: ")
        drop(item, inventory)
```

Спасибо за любую предоставленную помощь.

Comment: Все-таки будет лучше, если Вы сами отредактируете свой вопрос - нужно убрать всю лирику, не относящуюся к делу, и четко описать проблему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask